# How to edit view name if mobile in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the code from: 
http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/02/23/a-better-way-to-add-mobile-pages-to-a-rails-site/

```
def check_for_mobile
    session[:mobile_override] = params[:_mobile] if params[:_mobile]
    prepare_for_mobile if mobile_device?
end

def prepare_for_mobile
    prepend_view_path Rails.root + 'app' + 'views_mobile'
end

def mobile_device?
    if session[:mobile_override]
      session[:mobile_override] == "1"
    else
      # Season this regexp to taste. I prefer to treat iPad as non-_mobile.
      (request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/) && (request.user_agent !~ /iPad/)
    end
end
helper_method :mobile_device?
```

This is great and works fine, but how would I change the view name vs. just the view path? It's a personal preference, but I'd rather have my mobile views like this:

/app/views/users/index_mobile.html.erb
vs.
/app/views_mobile/users/index.html.erb

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `render` method:

```
render is_mobile? ? :index_mobile : :index
```

See [2.2.2 Rendering an Action’s View](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).

I doubt it's possible to render views stored outside of `/app/views`. Even if it would be possible, it would be unwise as it breaks Rails' path conventions.